# Get Attachments REST API php

Tags: php, outlook-restapi

I am really confused in how to get a mail attachment from Outlook REST API and show it as a download link. The documentation is not precise and I have multiple forums but none could help me with it.
I took an OOP approach and this is a snippet of my code getting the attachment.

```
//
$getMessagesUrl = self::$outlookApiUrl."/Me/messages/".$message_id."/attachments/$attachment_id";

return self::makeApiCall($access_token, $user_email, "GET", $getMessagesUrl);

///
A get a response like this:

///

{

    "@odata.context": "https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/$metadata#Me/Messages('AAMkAGI2THVSAAA%3D')/Attachments/$entity",

    "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.OutlookServices.FileAttachment",

    "@odata.id": "https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/Users('ddfcd489-628b-40d7-b48b-57002df800e5@1717622f-1d94-4d0c-9d74-709fad664b77')/Messages('AAMkAGI2THVSAAA=')/Attachments('AAMkAGI2j4kShdM=')",

    "Id": "AAMkAGI2j4kShdM=",

    "LastModifiedDateTime": "2014-10-20T00:41:52Z",

    "Name": "minutes.docx",

    "ContentType": "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document",

    "Size": 11585,

    "IsInline": false,

    "ContentId": null,

    "ContentLocation": null,

    "ContentBytes": "UEsDBBQABgAIAAAAIQDCAAA4KQAAAAA="
}
////
```

My problem is how to get the actual URL so I can see and download the file. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to do it. I am using PHP and the steps are below.

## 1st: decode ContentBytes

`$name=$attachment["Name"];
 $decocedData = base64_decode($attach["ContentBytes"]);`

## 2nd: create a file with and write the decoded data in it

`$myfile = fopen("files/$name","w");
 fwrite($myfile,$decocedData);
 fclose($myfile);`

## 3rd: display the url as href

`echo "<a href='files/$name' download>$name</a>";`